# Refreshing variables shown in a html file by pressing a button

Tags: django

I have a program that takes data from a sensor in my raspberry pi and I want the data taken from the raspberry to be shown in a web page, the idea is that it can be updated every time you press a button that its in the web. I'm right now using django to create the web, but I don't know if it is too much complex for what I'm trying to do.
Here I have my data extractor code:

```py
import bme280
import smbus2
from time import sleep

port = 1
address = 0x76 # Adafruit BME280 address. Other BME280s may be different
bus = smbus2.SMBus(port)



bme280.load_calibration_params(bus,address)


bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
humidity  = bme280_data.humidity
pressure  = bme280_data.pressure
ambient_temperature = bme280_data.temperature
```

Here I have the django views.py file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/jordi/weather-station/data')
from bme280_sensor import humidity, ambient_temperature, pressure
from subprocess import run,PIPE


# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'humitat': humidity, 'temperatura': ambient_temperature, 'pressio': pressure})

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("EL temps de vilafant")
```

and finally here I have my html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Aqui podras veure el temps de vilafant en un futur, no tinguis presa</p>
    <h1>La humitat d'avui és: {{humitat}}</h1>
    <h1>La temperatura d'avui és: {{temperatura}} Cº</h1>
    <h1>La pressió d'avui és: {{pressio}}</h1>

    <input type="button"><br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

How can I make that the button created in the html file updates the variables that are shown in the html page?

I have tried to create a button and link it so it can run the data extractor file another time but found that the variables shown in the page are not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that because `views.py` will be loaded only `once` when you start your application, so your variables will not change. You need to write a function to reload your data, something like:

sensors.py
(I tested by mocking values, so its a different function)

```py
...
def update_sensor_data():
    bme280_data = bme280.sample(bus,address)
    data = {    
        'humitat': bme280_data.humidity,
        'pressio': bme280_data.pressure,
        'temperatura': bme280_data.temperature
    }
    return data
```

views.py

```
from .sensors import update_sensor_data

def home(request):
    data = update_sensor_data()
    return render(request, 'base.html', data)
```

And then use the button to send a `GET` request to your view thus reloading your data and rendering the page with the new values:

home.html

```
<body>
    <p>Aqui podras veure el temps de vilafant en un futur, no tinguis presa</p>
    <h1>La humitat d'avui és: {{humitat}}</h1>
    <h1>La temperatura d'avui és: {{temperatura}} Cº</h1>
    <h1>La pressió d'avui és: {{pressio}}</h1>

    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" >
        <button>Update</button>
    </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you connect the button to a url path and poll every x seconds. I recommend something like
 [this](https://htmx.org/docs/#polling)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).